# Code to test if Android bootloader is unlocked?

Tags: android, bootloader

Is there a way to check in code whether or not a device's bootloader has been unlocked?  Not whether the devices is rooted, just the bootloader status.

There's this command of course:

```
fastboot oem device-info
```

But I need to be able to make the same determination in C++ (preferred) or Java when running in regular (not fastboot) mode.

Comment: any answer for this question?

Comment: Never got a response.